# Golang crashing in production

Tags: linux, go

I have a go program which connects to a tcp server and publishes that message to web service. the application works fine in the first go and it panics after a week or so. I am not sure why. the stack trace isn't helpful either.
(I cross compile from mac os to linux; env GOOS=linux GOARCH=386  go build)
could some one give pointers on what might be the issue?

the tcp server connection might go off once in a while; I have build the reconnection logic by hand. 
the error condition would be applicable to posting as well. the internet connection might break at any time; so "dns" resolver which go uses by default "cgo" was panicking. I had recompile with the "netgo" to use pure go network implementation.

### Stack trace

```
net.runtime_pollWait(0xf75c12d8, 0x72, 0x18690000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55 net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x18a6bb38, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)/usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0x18a6bb38, 0x0, 0x0) _poll_runtime.go:78 +0x33
    net.(*netFD).Read(0x18a6bb00, 0x18cd6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0xf75bc018, 0x18690000)/usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:232 +0x19anet.(*conn).Read(0x18cd4d78, 0x18cd6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xb9
    net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0xf75fc018, 0x18cd4d78, 0x1889770c, 0x18cd6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2c3620, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1370 +0x55
    net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0x18cd29e0, 0x18cd6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x8056f0c, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:126 +0xae
    bufio.(*Reader).fill(0x1881b7d0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x172
    bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0x1881b7d0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xad
    net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0x188976e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:876 +0xe3
    created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:685 +0xabc
```

GO program [go program](https://play.golang.org/p/Xu7clWnXTb)

```
  package main

 import (
  "bufio"
  "bytes"
  "encoding/json"
  "flag"
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "net/http"
  "time"
  )

  var (
    server             = flag.String("deamon", "127.0.0.1:7070", "AMQP URI")
    msgRoutingKey      = flag.String("routingKey", "routingKey", " routing key")
    msgexchange        = flag.String("exchange", "exchange", " excahnge ")
    mywebserviceServer = flag.String("mywebservice-server", "127.0.0.1:8080",      "mywebserviceServer:port ")
  )

   func init() {

     flag.Parse()
   }

   type TcpConnector struct {
    Outbound      chan string
    Inbound       chan string
    Addr          string
    ReconnectTime time.Duration
   }

type Message struct {
  RoutingKey string `json:"routingKey"`
  Exchange   string `json:"exchange"`
  Data       string `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
  start := time.Now()
  tcpClient := NewTcpConnector(*server)
  elapsed := time.Since(start)
  fmt.Println("the connecting params are  %s", *server, *msgexchange, *msgRoutingKey, *mywebserviceServer)
  fmt.Println("connecting to daemon took %s", elapsed)
   go func() {
    for msg := range tcpClient.Inbound {
        fmt.Println(msg)
        rabbitMessage := Message{
            RoutingKey: *msgRoutingKey,
            Exchange:   *msgexchange,
            Data:       msg,
        }
        mywebserviceMessageEndpoint :=    fmt.Sprintf("http://%s/v1/messages/publish", *mywebserviceServer)
        doPut(mywebserviceMessageEndpoint, &rabbitMessage)

      }
    }()

   select {}
 }

func doPut(url string, rabbitMessage *Message) {
 start := time.Now()
 b, err := json.Marshal(rabbitMessage)
 client := &http.Client{}
 request, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(b))
 request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
 request.Header.Add("accept", "application/json")
 response, err := client.Do(request)
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
 } else {
    defer response.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("   ", response.StatusCode)
    hdr := response.Header
    for key, value := range hdr {
        fmt.Println("   ", key, ":", value)
    }

 }

 elapsed := time.Since(start)
 fmt.Println("posting to mywebservice took %s", elapsed)

}

func NewTcpConnector(addr string) *TcpConnector {
 tcpConnector := &TcpConnector{
    Addr:          addr,
    Outbound:      make(chan string, 100),
    Inbound:       make(chan string, 100),
    ReconnectTime: 30 * time.Second,
 }
 tcpConnector.connect()
 return tcpConnector
}

//keep connect private, will be in trouble if got called twice
func (tcpConnector *TcpConnector) connect() {
 conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", tcpConnector.Addr)
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to make a connection", err)
    time.Sleep(tcpConnector.ReconnectTime)
    tcpConnector.connect()
    return
 }

go func() {
    for msg := range tcpConnector.Outbound {

        _, err = fmt.Fprintf(conn, msg+"\n")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed sending event", err)
            time.Sleep(tcpConnector.ReconnectTime)
            tcpConnector.connect()
            break
        }

    }
}()
go func() {
    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(conn, 1024*1024)
    for {
        message, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("Message Received: %s", message)
        tcpConnector.Inbound <- string(message)
        fmt.Println("Message sent to chan")
    }

    fmt.Println("reconnecting...")
    tcpConnector.connect()
}()
fmt.Println("Connected tcp")
}
```

Comment: Is that really the entire stack trace? Are you using the current version of Go?

Comment: go version go1.5.1 darwin/amd64

Comment: I am outputting the response on to console;

Comment: There's got to be more output than that. That's just a single runtime goroutine stack, likely has nothing to do with your error, and you don't have an error message of any sort. From a quick glance at your code, you have a function with the comment "will be in trouble if got called twice", but it contains no mutex and is called twice from 2 different goroutines. (it wouldn't hurt to update to the supported version of Go too, currently 1.6.2)

Comment: the second connect block is the error recovery scenario as in; if the tcp connection goes down;  wait for configured time and then reconnect.           if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to make a connection", err)
    time.Sleep(tcpConnector.ReconnectTime)
    tcpConnector.connect()
    return
 }

Comment: If your tcp connection goes down, you call connect from one goroutine (which blocks and may call connect recursively as long as there's connectivity problems, or hang indefinitely as there's no timeout), while the other goroutine sleeps then also calls connect, which may already be in progress, and which may also call connect recursively or block indefinitely. Either one of those connect calls may spawn 2 more goroutines, which each have the chance to call connect themselves. I can't tell what your error is with the limited info here, but your TcpConnector doesn't really work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113560/discussion-between-harry-and-jimb).

Comment: That seems to be a possibility but even if there is no timeout explicitly mentioned won't every os itself have a time out like 3 min ??

Comment: a timeout on what? There aren't global timeouts for syscalls

Comment: / With or without a timeout, the operating system may impose         // its own earlier timeout. For instance, TCP timeouts are         // often around 3 minutes.

Comment: https://golang.org/src/net/dial.go?s=448:2248#L7

Comment: the key points are  "*may* impose" and "*often around* 3 minutes". But it's not guaranteed. A recv call will by default wait indefinitely, or if keepalive is enabled, a dead connection may close anywhere from 30min to many hours after the call. This is all beside the point. You need to figure out why you got a panic (you need to provide the full stack trace, and better yet run your program with the race detector), and you need to fix the retry logic in your `TcpConnector`.

Comment: @JimB: I'll try to get the stacktrace; I did recompile the program with --race option. I might have to wait for a week before I get the crash!!! Thanks in advance for taking out the time in helping me out !!!

Comment: @JimB: the stack trace : http://pastebin.com/nJ8nMVrg

Comment: you've run out of threads for some reason. I can't tell why, but it failed here when the GC tried to create one (Are you certain that you're not using the cgo net resolver? Are you using systemd with a low thread limit?Are you setting GOMAXPROCS to some unreasonable value?). Though none of this really matters when the code above is broken, never closes sockets, can recurse indefinitely while reconnecting, can get out of sync reading and writing from different sockets, and so on.

Comment: Yes I am compiling with 'netgo' flag and 'GOMaxprocs' isn't defaulted to cores available as of 1.5 ?? I am not sure on systemd limits